# how to download coastal data

Tags: r, dictionary

I'm trying to calculate the distance between some points and the nearest point of the coastline. To do so, I need to download the coastline data (coordinates) from an specific area

I have used getbb from osmdata

```
getbb (place_name = "England") %>%
  opq () %>% 
  add_osm_feature("natural", "coastline") %>% 
  osmdata_sf()
```

however, getbb only allows me to download the data from an specific country in the list, but what I need is the coastline of the whole Baltic Sea. Is there a way to set getbb in a way that downloads the coastline data of a custom bounding box?

Comment: There are scripts to help download coastline data at [fossgis/osmdata](https://github.com/fossgis/osmdata)  - these are *not* related to R package of same name, but will get you coastlines as linestrings which can be easily read with `sf`

Answer (score 0):

I have minimal/no experience with osmdata, but looked at it. Getbb is getting a custom bounded box and thus you don't need to set it to anything. Getbb also only allows for one input, so you cannot combine areas. I tried with minimal success to search for "Baltic Sea".

However, opq() allows for a bbox argument:

(from help): Either (i) four numeric values specifying the maximal and minimal longitudes and latitudes; (ii) a character string passed to getbb to be converted to a numerical bounding box; or (iii) a matrix representing a bounding polygon as returned from getbb(..., format_out = "polygon").

Thus, if you can create a custom bounding box outside of the initial query you should be able to move forward.

```
library(osmdata)
 custom_area <- opq (bbox = c(-86.7523, -86.726, 2.3, 2.1), timeout = 60) %>% 
                add_osm_feature("natural", "coastline") %>% 
                osmdata_sf()
```

Another potential option is in the opq help:

```
q1 <- getbb ("portsmouth", display_name_contains = "USA") %>%
                opq () %>% 
                add_osm_feature("amenity", "restaurant") 
q2 <- getbb ("portsmouth", display_name_contains = "USA") %>%
                opq () %>% 
                add_osm_feature("amenity", "pub") 
c (osmdata_sf (q1), osmdata_sf (q2)) # all objects that are restaurants OR pubs
```

Obviously substituting the restaurants/pubs for countries. I'm having a few issues connecting to the database, but those are two options I could find.